# Avahi upgrade failes

Tags: avahi

```
uname -a
Linux nas 3.5.0-41-generic #64~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 12 16:50:04 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**can you help me with this one?**

```
sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  avahi-daemon
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
30 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/69.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 259768 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace avahi-daemon 0.6.30-5ubuntu2 (using .../avahi-daemon_0.6.30-5ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb) ...
avahi-daemon stop/waiting
Unpacking replacement avahi-daemon ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/avahi-daemon_0.6.30-5ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/avahi/services', which is also in package udisks 1.0.4-    5ubuntu2.1
avahi-daemon start/running, process 942
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/avahi-daemon_0.6.30-5ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these commands on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get purge udisks
sudo apt-get upgrade
```